# OneNote for OS X, How to type a dash then a space without turning it into a list

Tags: ms-office, formatting

I am currently using OneNote for OS X to take notes at college.

I currently need to do maths when using OneNote. Whenever I type a `-` then a space OneNote automatically turns that into a list, when I disable the list it then removes the '-' which I made. This means I am unable to do what I want. Here are some examples on what I mean.

I want to do

```
  0111
- 0001
------
  0001
```

However OneNote turns it into a list like this

```
   0111
    -   0001
```

As you can see, this is rather annoying, I then remove the list buy chasing list style none however that removes the dash, if I was then to do a space at the beginning it would be turned back into a list. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After it changes to a list, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

It's a common routine for things auto-corrected by apps if you don't want them to be auto-corrected, same with MS Office for Windows.

Comment: Ah, Thanks. So I basically undo what it done then?

Comment: Yup, I am yet to try it on my Macbook Air though. But that's how it works with emojis when you want them to display text instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter on emojis. I won't be using them. :)